# Display conversion table from 2 user inputs

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic-data

This is the code I have written using html and javascript and it essentially gets the user input `(n)` from the first text box and converts miles to kilometres from `0 to n`, however, I have now created another text box which needs another user input `(x)` so then if the user inputs `n = 3` and `x = 9` it will show the conversions from miles to kilometres starting from `3` all the way till `9` but i'm not sure how to go about that.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function conversion(n)
{
  <!--if(n<=1) return 1;-->
  return n/0.62137;
}

function conversionTable(range)
{
  divStr="<table border=1><tr><td>Miles</td><td>Kilometres</td></tr>";
  for(i=0;i<=range;i++)
    divStr+="<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + conversion(i) + "</td></tr>";
  document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML=divStr;
}

function getnputValue()
{
  return document.getElementById("rangeTxt").value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
    Start : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt value=""/>
    Finish : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt2 value=""/>
    <br>
    <button onClick="conversionTable(getnputValue())">Press to get     result</button>
</p>
<div id="divResult">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what actually want to convey?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass both input's values to conversionTable, the way you did, and instead of starting the loop from 0, use the start value:

```js
function conversion(n)
{
  <!--if(n<=1) return 1;-->
  return n/0.62137;
}

function conversionTable(rangeStart, rangeEnd)
{
  divStr="<table border=1><tr><td>Miles</td><td>Kilometres</td></tr>";
  for(i=rangeStart;i<=rangeEnd;i++)
    divStr+="<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + conversion(i) + "</td></tr>";
  document.getElementById("divResult").innerHTML=divStr;
}

function getnputValue()
{
  return document.getElementById("rangeTxt").value;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Start : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt value=""/>
    Finish : <input type=textbox id=rangeTxt2 value=""/>
    <br>
    <button onClick="conversionTable(getnputValue(), document.getElementById('rangeTxt2').value)">Press to get     result</button>
</p>
<div id="divResult">
</div>
```